# Access VBa - insert same ID into joined table

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I insert ID into join table from another form ? Inserted record ID has to be same as in form that I'm currently positioned (FirstForm).I'm doing this while another form (SecondForm) is opened too.

Here is what I tried:

```
 If CurrentProject.AllForms("SecondForm").IsLoaded Then

    DoCmd.OpenForm "JoinTableForm", , , "IDx=" & Forms![FirstForm].Form![IDx]

          If Forms![JoinTableForm].Form![IDx] = Null Then

              Forms![JoinTableForm].Form![IDx] = Forms![FirstForm].Form![IDx]

          End If
```

This code is executed from module, and IDx isn't inserted into JoinTableForm. But, If I'm on this form (while opened) code works - like this:

```
Me.IDx=Forms![FirstForm].Form![IDx]
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You're checking if `SecondForm` is loaded, but getting a value off of a form called `FirstForm`, but there's also a `JoinTableForm` ? How are these forms set up, exactly? It's a little confusing as the question is currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved It. I just had to put line in Exit,Before_Update events and my "Save" sub:

```
Me.IDx=Forms![FirstForm].Form![IDx]
```

Ofcourse, FirstForm has to be opened meanwhile. Sorry for bad posting of thread.